# Mercurial set up ACL

Tags: mercurial, acl

I'm trying to set up ACL. I've got it mostly working. However, I've got a couple of specific questions.

Basically, I'm trying to set up a group @group that will be allowed to access a bunch of branches of the form xxxx-integration-xxxx. What I want to do is:

```
[acl.allow.branches]
*integration* = @group
```

however, that doesn't seem to work. Is there an easy way to do this?

thanks

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension
This has a good explanation about setting up groups and access with acl

Comment: yes, that's what I used to create my hgrc file to begin with. However, it doesn't actually answer my question. I can create specific branches that only a group can write to. I can say that some people can write to ANY branch, but what I want is a large subset of branches that only a group can write to. It doesn't tell me that I can do that. If the answer is no, I'll be disappointed, but move on...

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking on pretxnchangegroup and writing a python script that gets the branch and the user and figure it out in there.  There is no ACL premade stuff for named branches that i know of.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488604/blocking-write-access-to-a-specific-branch-in-a-single-mercurial-repository

Comment: I don't understand. the ACL extension does exactly that. It works on named branches. It just doesn't do any work on the NAMES themselves, except direct equality matching, or complete glob expansion as far as I can tell.